# How to retrieve action error messages using multiple redirect actions in struts2?

Tags: validation, struts2, interceptor

I'm using struts2 and my struts.xml looks like this:

```
<action name="actionA" class="actionAClass">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">actionD</result>
    <result name="error" type="redirectAction">actionB</result>
</action>
<action name="actionB" class="actionBClass">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">actionC</result>
    <result name="error" type="redirectAction">actionC</result>
</action>
<action name="actionC" class="actionAClass">
    <result name="success">homepage.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">homepage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

As you can see, actionA error result redirect to actionB and actionB error result redirect to actionC. At the end, I want to display the error message at the homepage.jsp but homepage is loaded only when actionC is called.
However using actions like this, when homepage is loaded, all the action error messages are lost.

I've also tried using interceptors in struts.xml between actions like below but still I'm not able to retrieve the error messages:

```
<action name="actionA" class="actionAClass">
    <interceptor-ref name="store">
        <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">actionD</result>
    <result name="error" type="redirectAction">actionB</result>
</action>

<action name="actionB" class="actionBClass">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">actionC</result>
    <result name="error" type="redirectAction">actionC</result>
</action>

<action name="actionC" class="actionAClass">
    <interceptor-ref name="store">
        <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

    <result name="success">homepage.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">homepage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Please help how do I retrieve action error messages using multiple redirect actions.

Comment: All the field/error/action messages stored in session to carry forward to next action on redirect (message store interceptor). Try to debug (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.1.2/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/MessageStoreInterceptor.java) when you are message getting lost.

Comment: How do you add error messages?

Comment: Getter, setters for the Actions? How do you display it on the Homepage? More code please, the error will be somewhere you didn't look at.

Comment: I'm adding error messages using addActionError(message) in the calling method of action and returning result as input. In the jsp, I'm adding struts <s:actionerror/> tag to retrieve error message.

Comment: There is no input result in your mapping.